# How can I copy-paste questions/answers with the latex symbols intact?

Tags: support

Some answers in physics.stackexchange seem to me so extremely brilliant! I would like to join some of the best ones in a single document by copy-paste. How can I do that, preserving the LaTeX code?

(Some of the gems happen even in very innocent questions... I don't know how many people have I already told in the last weeks, about that answer to the question "why the kinetic energy goes as $v^{2}$ " involving two pieces of clay and a thermometer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct copy-paste works if it's an HTML document in Word. Sometimes.

Otherwise, here's a trick: open `about:blank` (URL bar), type `javascript:document.body.contentEditable=true` in the URL bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now, copy-paste the LaTeX-formatted stuff. It ought to work. You can type and modify stuff as well. Then, save the HTML document and/or print to pdf. [This userscript may help in cleaning up posts for better copy-pasting](https://stackapps.com/questions/3307/print-this-post)

Note that you should attribute the owner of each post (see [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)).

---

If you want un-mathified LaTeX source:

- For individual equations: right click, `show math as`>TeX commands
- For the whole post: Click "edit", copy-paste the source code to [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), see the preview.

Comment: Does the trick work in any browser?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Pretty much. Older versions of FF and IE won't support it. And FF/IE don't have a built in print-to-pdf, you have to have Acrobat installed. But for all intents and purposes, yeah, it works everywhere :)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work (firefox, kubuntu 10.04, java installed)

Comment: Isn't there any way to simply make my navigator show latex commands instead of rendered formulas? I remember to have seen it somewhere...

Comment: @Eduardo: Right click on the formula, a little menu shows up. Show math as>TeX commands. If you want to see the commands embedded in the post, copy-paste the source (you can find it via "edit"), into the meta.physics "ask question" box, and look in the preview area. That will unmathify everything.

Comment: @Eduardo: Hmm, yeah, it seems to depend. On Chrome it works, but some formatting is lost...

Comment: Oh, finding the source via "edit" is nice enough, thanks! (I was thinking I couldn't do it without much reputation). If you add that to your answer, I'll mark it as "answered".

Comment: @Eduardo: Done :)